# Хочу вставить свое изображение в pycharm

Tags: pycharm

хотел бы попросить вас кто знает как сделать так чтоб в этой красной рамке которою я нарисовал в paint было изображение, искал в настройках где это меняется но не нашел помогите пожалуйста.
Заранее спасибо.
[image: Хочу чтоб в этой красной рамке было мое изображение]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File - Settings - Appearance & Behavior - Appearance - Background Image...

Comment: Спасибо вам большое.